# Cant use the posit algorithm from opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use POSIT algo implemented in opencv in my project. I am having compilation error on running the code:

Error:

```
src/calib/POSIT.h:26:36: error: ‘CvMatr32f’ does not name a type
  void createOpenGLMatrixFrom(const CvMatr32f &rotationMatrix,
                                    ^
src/calib/POSIT.h:26:47: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘rotationMatrix’ with no type [-fpermissive]
  void createOpenGLMatrixFrom(const CvMatr32f &rotationMatrix,
                                               ^
src/calib/POSIT.h:27:12: error: ‘CvVect32f’ in namespace ‘cv’ does not name a type
      const cv::CvVect32f &translationVector);
            ^
src/calib/POSIT.h:27:27: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘translationVector’ with no type [-fpermissive]
      const cv::CvVect32f &translationVector);
                           ^
src/calib/POSIT.h:41:2: error: ‘CvPOSITObject’ does not name a type
  CvPOSITObject* positObject;
```

I tried to find out how to remove it but couldn't find a working solution online. I am on opencv 3.1 .

POSIT code I am using is:

POSIT.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
//#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <vector>

#define FOCAL_LENGTH 760.0

class POSIT {
public:
    POSIT();
    virtual ~POSIT();

    void initialize(double cameraMatrix[3 * 3], const double &aWidth, const double &aHeight,
            const double &nearPlane, const double &farPlane);

    void poseEstimation();
    void createOpenGLMatrixFrom(const CvMatr32f &rotationMatrix,
                    const cv::CvVect32f &translationVector);
    void projectModelPoints(float *pose, std::vector<CvPoint2D32f> &projectedPoints);

    double width, height; //Image size
    double cameraMatrix[3 * 3];
    float posePOSIT[16];
    float poseReal[16];
    float projectionMatrix[16];
    float shift[3];

    std::vector<CvPoint3D32f> modelPoints;
    std::vector<CvPoint2D32f> srcImagePoints;
    std::vector<CvPoint2D32f> estimatedImagePoints;

    CvPOSITObject* positObject;

    //mine
    float rotation_matrix[9];
    float translation_vector[3];

};
```

POSIT.cpp:

```
#include "POSIT.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

POSIT::POSIT() {
}

POSIT::~POSIT() {
    cvReleasePOSITObject(&positObject);
    //  cvReleaseMat(&intrinsics);
}

void POSIT::initialize(double cameraMatrix[3 * 3], const double &aWidth, const double &aHeight,
        const double &nearPlane, const double &farPlane) {
    width = aWidth;
    height = aHeight;

    //Generate four model points
    //The first one must be (0,0,0) so we shift all
    shift[0] = modelPoints[0].x;
    shift[1] = modelPoints[0].y;
    shift[2] = modelPoints[0].z;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < modelPoints.size(); i++) {
        modelPoints[i].x -= shift[0];
        modelPoints[i].y -= shift[1];
        modelPoints[i].z -= shift[2];
    }

    //Create the POSIT object with the model points
    positObject = cvCreatePOSITObject(&modelPoints[0], (int) modelPoints.size());

    //  intrinsics = cvCreateMat( 3, 3, CV_32F );
    //  cvSetZero( intrinsics );
    //  initializeIntrinsics( width, height );
    //  createOpenGLProjectionMatrix( width, height, nearPlane, farPlane );
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        this->cameraMatrix[i] = cameraMatrix[i];
    }
    //POSIT receives a single focal length
    //  this->cameraMatrix[0]=  FOCAL_LENGTH;
    //  this->cameraMatrix[1*3+1]=  FOCAL_LENGTH;
    this->cameraMatrix[1 * 3 + 1] = this->cameraMatrix[0];
}

void transpose(float *in, int m, int n, float *out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            out[i * m + j] = in[j * n + i];
        }
    }
}

void POSIT::poseEstimation() {
    //  CvMatr32f rotation_matrix = new float[9];
    //  CvVect32f translation_vector = new float[3];
    //set posit termination criteria: 100 max iterations, convergence epsilon 1.0e-5
    CvTermCriteria criteria = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1.0e-4f);
    //  cvPOSIT( positObject, &srcImagePoints[0], FOCAL_LENGTH, criteria, rotation_matrix, translation_vector );
    cvPOSIT(positObject, &srcImagePoints[0], cameraMatrix[0], criteria, rotation_matrix,
            translation_vector);

    createOpenGLMatrixFrom(rotation_matrix, translation_vector);

    float rotation_matrix_trans[9];
    transpose(rotation_matrix, 3, 3, rotation_matrix_trans);

    // RT= [R' T'];
    float RT[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            RT[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            RT[i][j] = rotation_matrix_trans[i * 3 + j];
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        RT[3][j] = translation_vector[j];
    }
    RT[3][3] = 1;

    CvMat RTMatrix = cvMat(4, 4, CV_32F, RT);

    // shiftR is the translation matrix, inverting the shift we've done before calling POSIT
    float shiftR[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            shiftR[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    shiftR[0][0] = shiftR[1][1] = shiftR[2][2] = shiftR[3][3] = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        shiftR[j][3] = -shift[j];
    }
    CvMat shiftRMatrix = cvMat(4, 4, CV_32F, shiftR);

    // result = [R' T']*shiftR'
    float result[16];
    CvMat resultMatrix = cvMat(4, 4, CV_32F, result);
    cvGEMM(&RTMatrix, &shiftRMatrix, 1.0, NULL, 0.0, &resultMatrix, CV_GEMM_A_T);

    // return R and T from result
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            rotation_matrix[i * 3 + j] = result[i * 4 + j];
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        translation_vector[j] = result[j * 4 + 3];
    }
    //      printMatrix(RT[0],4,4);
    //      printMatrix(shiftR[0],4,4);
    //      printMatrix(result,4,4);

    //Show the results
#ifdef _DEBUG
    cout << "\n\n-......- POSE ESTIMATED -......-\n";
    cout << "\n-.- MODEL POINTS -.-\n";
    for ( size_t p=0; p<modelPoints.size(); p++ )
    cout << modelPoints[p].x << ", " << modelPoints[p].y << ", " << modelPoints[p].z << "\n";

    cout << "\n-.- IMAGE POINTS -.-\n";
    for ( size_t p=0; p<modelPoints.size(); p++ )
    cout << srcImagePoints[p].x << ", " << srcImagePoints[p].y << " \n";

    cout << "\n-.- REAL POSE\n";
    for ( size_t p=0; p<4; p++ )
    cout << poseReal[p] << " | " << poseReal[p+4] << " | " << poseReal[p+8] << " | " << poseReal[p+12] << "\n";

    cout << "\n-.- ESTIMATED POSE\n";
    for ( size_t p=0; p<4; p++ )
    cout << posePOSIT[p] << " | " << posePOSIT[p+4] << " | " << posePOSIT[p+8] << " | " << posePOSIT[p+12] << "\n";
#endif

    //  delete rotation_matrix;
    //  delete translation_vector;
}

void POSIT::createOpenGLMatrixFrom(const CvMatr32f &rotationMatrix,
        const CvVect32f &translationVector) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        rotation_matrix[i] = rotationMatrix[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        translation_vector[i] = translationVector[i];
    }

    //coordinate system returned is relative to the first 3D input point    
    for (int f = 0; f < 3; f++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
            posePOSIT[c * 4 + f] = rotationMatrix[f * 3 + c]; //transposed
        }
    }
    posePOSIT[3] = 0.0;
    posePOSIT[7] = 0.0;
    posePOSIT[11] = 0.0;
    posePOSIT[12] = translationVector[0];
    posePOSIT[13] = translationVector[1];
    posePOSIT[14] = translationVector[2];
    posePOSIT[15] = 1.0;
}

void POSIT::projectModelPoints(float *pose, vector<CvPoint2D32f> &projectedPoints) {
    // The origin of the coordinates system is in the centre of the image
    projectedPoints.clear();
    CvMat poseMatrix = cvMat(4, 4, CV_32F, pose);
    for (size_t p = 0; p < modelPoints.size(); p++) {
        float modelPoint[] = { modelPoints[p].x, modelPoints[p].y, modelPoints[p].z, 1.0f };
        CvMat modelPointMatrix = cvMat(4, 1, CV_32F, modelPoint);
        float point3D[4];
        CvMat point3DMatrix = cvMat(4, 1, CV_32F, point3D);
        cvGEMM(&poseMatrix, &modelPointMatrix, 1.0, NULL, 0.0, &point3DMatrix, CV_GEMM_A_T);

        //Project the transformed 3D points
        CvPoint2D32f point2D = cvPoint2D32f(0.0, 0.0);
        if (point3D[2] != 0) {
            point2D.x = cameraMatrix[0 * 3 + 0] * point3D[0] / point3D[2];
            point2D.y = cameraMatrix[1 * 3 + 1] * point3D[1] / point3D[2];
        }
        projectedPoints.push_back(point2D);
    }
}
```

Comment: For OpenCV 2, you need to include `<opencv2/legacy/compat.hpp>`. OpenCV does not seem to have these symbols defined (at least, not in the /usr/include/opencv/ that comes with Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new to opencv and couldnt find this in docs. What is the alternative to these data types in opencv2 ?

Comment: It gives just this error now : src/calib/POSIT.h:42:2: error: ‘CvPOSITObject’ does not name a type
  CvPOSITObject* positObject;

Comment: `CvPOSITObject` seems to be defined in `<opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>`, not sure if that helps?

Comment: Dont know why but that didnt resolve the error

Comment: worked when I included <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d_c.h>

Answer (score 0):

General answer:
Go to your opencv directory (with for example Terminal in Linux, or Git Bash in Windows) and find the symbol among the include files:

```sh
cd ${LIB_DIR}/opencv3.4.13
rgrep CvPOSITObject include/ # recursive grep to find text in all include files
```

returns:

```sh
include/opencv2/calib3d/calib3d_c.h:typedef struct CvPOSITObject CvPOSITObject;
...
```

Solution is indeed to include `opencv2/calib3d/calib3d_c.h`